# Scaling Mesh and Amature Together [ShapeKeys]

Tags: animation, mesh, armature, unity, scale

is there a way to use a ShapeKey on Amature ?
I want to do a Character Creator in Unity.

So I create different ShapeKeys and then adjust them via Script in Unity.
But...

I want to have the modified Mesh to have the correct Armature attached to it, so I can make the basic Animation for each Character-Gender (Male, Female).
I'm relative new to Blender, but I can do some stuff, consider me an Amateur.

Help would be nice :)

Comment: While solutions to this are possible, they involve constraints-- which Unity won't read.  Anything you want to do, you'll need to implement in Unity, and the Blender stuff won't matter at all.  To my knowledge, Unity supports bone scaling (incl. non-uniform scaling) just fine, so you should be looking implementing your character creator by modifying the bones' scales rather than via shapekeys.  But know that animation designed for one set of proportions is not necessarily good animation when applied to a different set of proportions.

Comment: So rather than creating the Amature in Blender, create it in Unity itself and do the Model itself in Blender ? 

I might misunterstood something or was unclear, I use ShapeKeys to define for example the Face of my Model with some kind of old Age.

Comment: Create the armature in Blender.  But scale (and or move, rotate) the bones in Unity.  You'll essentially have a "character creator pose" to combine (via matrix multiplication) with your animations.  Combine with shapekeys as needed for deformations that can't be represented by your armature, deformations that don't require any adjustment to the positions of bones.